# How to ignore a lint rule for entire file in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am able to ignore the rule for individual variables like this:

```
class Class {
  // ignore: prefer_final_fields
  var _count = 0;

  // ignore: prefer_final_fields
  var _count2 = 0;
}
```

I want to use something like this but it doesn't work. How can I ignore the lint for entire class?

```
// ignore: prefer_final_fields (DOESN'T WORK)
class Class {
  var _count = 0;

  var _count2 = 0;
}
```

Comment: For reference, see https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To ignore a rule

- #### For entire file:

  Use `ignore_for_file` instead of simple `ignore`:

  ```dart
  // ignore_for_file: prefer_final_fields (WORKS)
  class Class {
    var _count = 0;

    var _count2 = 0;
  }
  ```
- #### For the whole project:

  Open the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your project and add the following lines:

  ```
  linter:
    rules:
      prefer_final_fields: false
  ```