# Bad state: No element

Tags: flutter, dart

i just want to know what is that for? and when it is coming, is it API problem?

```
         BlocBuilder<OrderBloc, OrderState>(
                  builder: (context, finalstate) {
                    if (state is OrderLoaded) {
                      for (var item in state.orderSent) {
                        totalweightsforsent.add(item.totalWeight);
//right here when i fetch the data from API and when it is done it is not going forward anymore
                      }
                      for (var item in state.orderPackaging) {
                        totalforpacking.add(item.totalWeight);
                      }
```

Comment: give some example code where the error occurrs.

Comment: If there is error log, please provide it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, its not an API problem, it is there for some reason

Let's look at the example of `firstWhere` which gets the color string from the list

**InValid Color String**

```
void main() {
  List<String> list = ['red', 'yellow', 'pink', 'blue'];
  var newList = list.firstWhere((element) => element.contains('green'), 
      orElse: () => 'No matching color found');
  print(newList);
}
```

**Output:**

No matching Color found

**Valid Color String**

```
 void main() {
      List<String> list = ['red', 'yellow', 'pink', 'blue'];
      var newList = list.firstWhere((element) => element.contains('blue'), 
          orElse: () => 'No matching color found');
      print(newList);
    }
```

**Output:**

blue

Above, all are valid cases but if `orElse()` block gets missing there it will throw  `BadStateException`

```
void main() {
  List<String> list = ['red', 'yellow', 'pink', 'blue'];
  var newList = list.firstWhere((element) => element.contains('green'));
  print(newList);
}
```

**Output:**

[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(171)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: No element

Comment: hi , i have same issue , can it be happening when api changes a key from its data base ?like when i request for `name` it would show the error because in api it is `Name` with capital N ? and can i find out which one has been changed ?

Answer (score 1):

Another way of seeing this error is to access properties like `first` or `last` of an empty list, for example:

```
final myList = [];
print(myList.first);
```

The solution is to always do `length > 0` check before accessing related list properties, eg using `isNotEmpty` property:

```
final myList = [];
if (myList.isNotEmpty) {
  print(myList.first);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `length > 0`, use `myList.isEmpty` or `myList.isNotEmpty` instead because it is 'faster and more readable'. See also: [dart linter 'prefer_is_empty'](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_is_empty.html)

Comment: @harlekintiger Thanks man, wasn't using this feature, it does look way more readable

Comment: I hightly recommend using the [flutter lints package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lints). Using flutters/darts recommendations it will mark all code that has a different best practice and link the specific linting rule. Pro Tip: You can disable certain rules if you disagree with the linter for any reason, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61889573/5913518)

Answer (score 0):

Use **firstWhereOrNull** in place of **firstWhere** and handle the null value.