# How to ignore all lint rules for a file or a project?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm seeing too many lint warnings in my file, for example:

> Avoid `print` calls in production code
>
> Prefer const with constant constructors
>
> Use key in widget constructors

I know how to [disable a rule for a specific line or for the entire file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61889572/12483095), but I want to know is there any way I can disable all these lint warnings with something like

```
// ignore_for_file: all
```

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#excluding-files

Comment: Alternatively... you could fix them.

Comment: @mmcdon20 Thanks, however the question wasn't about the analyzer but linter.

Comment: @nvoigt I know it can be fixed, not a big deal there, but I just wanted to know is there any way I can suppress all the warnings.

Comment: @iDecode, any file you list as excluded will not have lints applied to it.

Comment: @mmcdon20 Analyzer will also not be applied to it, so, this isn't a good solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the documentation,

```
// ignore_for_file: type=lint
```

should work. I don't have a project to test it right now though.

Answer (score 3):

in your analysis_options.yaml file:

```yaml
linter:
  rules:
    avoid_print: false
    # add more here ...
    # Available lints see: [https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/index.html][1]
```

Comment: I wanted to remove all the rules in one command, comment or phrase.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there is no such comment like that. These lint rules are coming from [`flutter_lints`](https://www.pub.dev/packages/flutter_lints) package which is included in your `analysis_options.yaml` file, So, open the file and comment this line out:

```yaml
// include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml
```

After this, save the file using <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

Just remove flutter_lints package from pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).